# Template non-type parameter?

Tags: c++, templates

Look at this piece of code:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <typename T, const T& temp>
void g()
{
    cout << temp << endl;
}

static const std::string s = "abc";

int main() {
    g<string, s>();
}
```

When I compile this with Visual C++ 2013 November CTP I get:

“error C2970: 'g' : template parameter 'temp' : 's' : an expression involving objects with internal linkage cannot be used as a non-type argument”

However, I read the following in the C++ 14 standard (14.3.2 [temp.arg.nontype]):

“a constant expression (5.19) that designates the address of a complete object with static storage duration and external or internal linkage or”

I interpret this as “constant expression with static storage duration and external linkage” or “constant expression with static storage duration and internal linkage”.
In my example above, isn’t the variable s a “constant expression with static storage duration and internal linkage” ?

When I change s to:

std::string s = "abc";

Then it compiles and it works, but isn’t that against the standard because now s is not a “constant expression” anymore.

Can someone shed some light on this?
Am I misinterpreting something here?

Comment: Try `namespace { const std::string s = "abc"; }`?

Comment: I tested your code on c++builder XE6 64bit and work. C++builder xe6 64bit uses a modified version of the CLang compatible with C11.

Comment: @Yakk That doesn't work either. It's complaining about internal linkage. `extern const ...` does work.

Comment: @Yakk: `const` objects declared at namespace level has internal linkage (unless it is declared `extern`).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In C++98 the language was (from 14.3.2/1): `the name of an object or function with external linkage...`. The change to allow internal linkage was included in C++11.

Your compiler is probably only compiling as the C++98 (or 03) standard, not C++11.

Comment: Thank you for the C++98 reference.
Then I suppose it's a compiler issue.

Answer (score 11):

Replace `static` with `extern`:

```
extern const std::string s = "abc";
```

The reason is that in C++98/C++03, references with *internal* linkage was not allowed as template argument.

Also note that *just* removing `static` *only* would **not** work if `const` is there, because `const` objects declared at namespace level has *internal* linkage (unless it is declared `extern`). So you need to use `extern` as shown above.